# Problema al mostrar datos después de recorrer un arreglo en Angular

Tags: angular

Buen día, intento recorrer dos arreglos que vienen de una API y mostrarlos en una tabla. Uno de los arreglos es para las columnas y el otro es para los datos.

El primer arreglo para las columnas de la tabla lo tengo de esta manera:

```
["Nombre", "Precio"]
```

Hasta este punto se imprimen bien los valores del arreglo.

El problema comienza cuando recorro el segundo arreglo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los valores se recorren en una sola columna en vez de que cada elemento del arreglo se recorra en una columna diferente.

De esta manera hago los recorridos de los arreglos

```
<table class="table table-responsive-md">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column}}</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
         <td>{{row}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Si algo estoy haciendo mal, me gustaría que me lo hicieran saber, al igual que cualquier comentario será de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas anidar un bucle para recorrer cada línea, añadiendo las celdas que hagan falta:

```
<table class="table table-responsive-md">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column}}</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
         <td *ngFor="let cell of row">{{cell}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Esto si me ha funcionado, no se me había ocurrido hacerlo de esa manera, en verdad ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

La parte del `tbody` es lo único que debes ajustar de la siguiente forma.

```
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
         <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
         <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Lo anterior dado que al recorrer arreglo `rows` cada elemento es un arreglo que contiene2 valores (indices) un string y un numerico; por ello, hay que referir de cada `row` que valor es el que se desplegara en cada `td`.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Estuve probando y si hace el recorrido correctamente, el detalle es que necesito hacerlo dinámico, ya que son varias consultas a la API, y no siempre serán dos columnas, pueden ser más, y en esa parte no se muy bien como pasarle el numero total de posiciones de cada elemento del arreglo, (por ejemplo `[Array(5), Array(5), Array(5)]`), ese número en este caso "5" es el que tendría que pasarle a `row` de esta manera`{{row[5]}}` para no escribir 5 veces la etiqueta `<td>`, no se si me doy a entender.

Comment: Saludos. En tal caso; mira ya hay una respuesta que da lo que pides.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya vi la respuesta, saludos.